# jquery - access form input field by Name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to access an form input field using just the element name?

If I were attempting this with the ID, it would look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="fname">

$("#fname").blur(function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("fname");
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

Is there any way to get access the element using the name is the field were??:

```
<input type="text" name="fname">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do this the correct selector is

```
$('input[name=fname]')
```

Comment: $('input[id=fname]')

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
$('[name="fname"]')
```

But it is recommended to use an id/class that is more efficient that doing an attribute selector.

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/
http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

See all the selectors you can use: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
$('input[name=fname]').on('blur', function() {
 //your code ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("input[name=fname]")`

Comment: a brief explanation as to why the answer works goes a long way to help others in the community

Answer (score 0):

you can see demo here [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/y5Lcsv3L/)

```
$("input[name='fname']").blur(function(e){
   alert('blur')
});
```